Variance of affine transformation of random variable
I am trying to understand how to derive the variance of an affine transformation of a random variable $X$. In particular, I don't understand the following result:
$$\mathbb{V}_X[Ax]=A\mathbb{V}_x[x]A^T$$
I know $\mathbb{V}_X[Ax]$ can be rewritten as:
$$\mathbb{V}_X[Ax]=\mathbb{E}[x^TA^TAx]-\mathbb{E}[Ax]^T\mathbb{E}[Ax]$$
I would like to use the linearity of the expectation, since $A$ is a constant matrix, and I know that $\mathbb{E}[Ax]=A\mathbb{E}[x]$, however I'm unsure how to use it in this case (in $\mathbb{E}[x^TA^TAx]$).

I think you mixed up the tranposes in your second line. Assuming that $X$ is a random column vector, where each element has finite variance. Denote $E[X] := \mu$, then the covariance matrix is defined as
$$
Var(X) = E((X - \mu)(X-\mu)^{T}) = E(XX^{T}) - E(X)\mu^{T} + \mu E(X^{T}) + \mu\mu^{T} = E(XX^{T}) - \mu\mu^{T}.
$$
This holds in fact for every random vector, so in particular also for $Y := AX + b$, where $A$ is a suitable matrix and $b$ a constant column vector. Now plug in the above to get
$$
Var(Y) = E((Y - \mu_{Y})(Y-\mu_{Y})^{T}) = E((AX - A\mu)(AX-A\mu)^{T}) = Var(AX).
$$
Then using the final result from the first line, we can rewrite
$$
Var(AX) = E(AXX^{T}A^{T}) - A\mu\mu^{T}A^{T} = A(E(XX^{T}) - \mu\mu^{T})A^{T} = A Var(X) A^{T}.
$$

Oh! Thank you, that makes sense!
